# Аналог `element.style.left = variable + 'px'`, только без 'px'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Имеется элемент:

```
let element = document.getElementById('id')
```

Я могу изменить его css-свойство `left` вот так:

```
let left = ...
highlight.style.left = left + 'px';
```

Есть ли аналог этого, только без необходимости писать `'px'`?

---

Например, с помощью jquery можно так:

```
$(element).css('left', left);
```

А можно без jquery (и без `'px'`)?

Comment: Напишите функцию, которая конкатенирует к переменной `px`, если 5 лишних символов вызывают сложности : )

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Нет. Нет.

Хотя ну ладно, на последний вопрос - да:

```js
var $ = (function () {
  var allowNumber = ['lineHeight', 'zIndex'];

  function $(el) {
    if (this instanceof $) {
      this.el = el;
    } else {
      return new $(el);
    }
  }

  $.prototype.css = function css(key, value) {
    key = key.replace(/-(\w)/g, function (m, ch) { return ch.toUpperCase() });
  
    if (+value == value && allowNumber.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      value += 'px';
    }
    
    this.el.style[key] = value;
    
    return this;
  }
  
  return $;
})();

$(document.querySelector("div")).css('left', 100).css('line-height', 3);
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
```

PS: Пиксели - зло.